# PictureBox with dynamic images

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

So what I'm trying to achieve is in theory a simple thing, as I can get it working in Chrome extensions and block the image.

I'm using ChromeDriver with adblock plus added in extensions to originally block the source of the image so it doesn't display since if you display the image once it won't display again, the image I'm trying to display in my picturebox is a image with a number (see link).

The code for generating the image is

```
"http://website.com/?q=i&ti=" + Math.Round(GetTime() / 1e3)
```

And output becomes

```
http://website.com/?q=i&ti=1492723237
```

I added a code to calculate ms since 1970-01-01

```
    private Int64 GetTime()
    {
        Int64 retval = 0;
        var st = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        TimeSpan t = (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - st);
        retval = (Int64)(t.TotalMilliseconds + 0.5);
        return retval;
    }
```

And to load the code in the picturebox with help of a timer to detect when that image is shown on the website is this.

```
    private void trialTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsElementPresent(By.Id("trial_opt_1")))
        {              
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("trial_reload")).Click();
            pictureBox1.Load("http://website.com/?q=i&ti=" + Math.Round(GetTime() / 1e3));
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

So as for the error I'm getting is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
```

**Would really want to know why the image is not shown, and how I can make it so it would appear as soon as it detects the image is shown on the website.**

Example of the image

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bs3k8KS.png]

Comment: Half a million Google hits on "windows forms parameter is not valid", we don't need one more.  Thanks for trying to contribute.

Comment: I don't quite get how the picture box could be the source of the error you are seeing ; my guess it's chrome driver rather than the picture box. To help tackle the problem, just plop down a breakpoint at the start of your `trialTimer.Tick` method and step-through it to see where the exception occurs.

Comment: (what would also help in this case is a full stacktrace if you have it)

Comment: The exception occurs at the `load()`, I have looked up the generated image, it creates the image as a png and then the headers are set on the page as a document file instead so the `load()` gives an error that the URL is not an image file.

Comment: You are trying to "hack" a captcha. Captcha codes usually will be generated or via an ajax call or via javascript. So, if it's retrieved via Ajax you must read the Javascript code and find the real URL for the image, else if it's generated from Javascript the "src" property of the image will be something like "data:image/png;base64,(lots of base64 data)". Unless you add more info like the page source code or the copied image URL it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Winforms supports URLs? Maybe it does, if so, maybe it's lousy at that!

Maybe. But try just downloading the image to a temp file first.

- get a temp file - io.path.tempfilename... (note this creates the file)
- download the file using Webclient download to temp path [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile(v=vs.110).aspx)
- when done, load the image
- Maybe skip the load and do picturebox1.image=new bitmap(temppath);

Comment: I have tried to download the image from the URL and load it into the picture box, but sadly the URL where the image is generated is set to a document page instead of an image so when it downloads the URL and set it to .png it doesn't work, even if I try to view it in windows 10 photo viewer.

Comment: @P.Samuel - that explains why the picturebox won't work - it won't do any magic that you can't do after you download the file, if you can't view the file you would be out of luck. You'll need the URL of just a picture. there's no special HTTPDOWNLOAD that will do anything differently.... Suggestion - drag the file onto an open notepad. Compare it to a regular PNG. You may see some crap in front that you can strip off and get just the PNG. OR... better yet, the URL somewhere in the text of the actual picture that the browser downloads. Strip that out ... and issue a second download to get it.

Comment: I mean if I go to the page where the image is generated I can right click and save the image and it will show in the photo viewer but if I add lines of code in my application to download the image from the given URL it doesn't show/work.

Comment: Try copying the path of the image via rightclicking (if in IE) or viewing the source or hitting F12. Paste it into test source code using HTTPDownload and you _should_ be able to open that. It's the same (and only!) operation for downloading. _The thing you will notice is that the URL you're feeding to the picturebox/httpdownload has got to be different than the one the browser sees - you have to figure out how to get the one from the other, and chances are, the image link is SOMEWHERE IN the text you download from the first link._ It's just HTML. key is this - LOOK at what downloaded.

Comment: Exactly the same url as the generated url, I tried the notepad thing but it makes no sense, both starts with %PNG and bunch of random characters.

Comment: The only thing that confuses me is, how come chrome extensions can display the URL as an image but windows forms can't output the URL as an image, the only thing I'm doing in my extension is loading in the URL and it will show up on the extension.